# The [[DEFAULT]] firebase app has not been initialized! flutter

Tags: flutter

I just created an app with flutter and firebase while running the code .I'm getting the firebase initialize error can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its just because you didn't call the firebase into your flutter code . Try my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

Make sure you added firebase core and firebase core plugin in pubsec.yaml and import the firebase core plugin in your dart file.

Comment: thank you! was wondering why when I called `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).add(...)` it wasn't working haha, now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0
```

now you have to call the function `Firebase.initializeApp();` in main function

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```